# Unity "player preferences" file format and contents

Tags: unity-game-engine

Upon quitting my application, I use `PlayerPrefs.Save()` to save the player preferences.

I understand this function writes all the modified preferences to disk.

So, I clicked on Start, typed `regedit` and opened it, went into `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and then `Software` and then I selected `Unity`.

So, now I can see the file (is this actually a file?) but I cannot figure out how to open it or see the contents...

Neither double-clicking on it works nor right-clicking on it brings up any menu with options.

How do I access the contents, or perhaps clear/flush it after a while?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact storage of [PlayerPrefs depends on the platform](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html). For Windows it is stored in [the registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry), as you have seen.

This is not an isolated file for your Unity game. As such, there is nothing really to open. You could edit the registry if you wanted to, but that's not really the appropriate way. Just keep using it via the provided PlayerPrefs API.

If you want to clear your playerprefs, you can call [PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll.html). This will clear all playerprefs data and would allow you to "simulate" a new user starting from scratch for example.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and informative answer. You addressed everything I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

You find the PlayerPrefs under:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/[NAME OF THE COMPANY YOU SPECIFIED IN PLAYESETTINGS]/[PRODUCTNAME YOU SPECIFIED IN PLAYERSETTINGS]

Answer (score 1):

If you had checked unity's documentation it is very well explained for each platform [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)

Answer (score 0):

For Win32 and Win64 builds it is in a Registry file editable from the registry.

In OS X builds it is in a plist file in ~/Library/Preferences These are in plist compliant format and can be edited in the standard OS X plist editor, or a text editor if you follow proper syntax.

In Windows Store builds it is in %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages[ProductPackageId]>\LocalState\playerprefs.dat (I don't know the format of this.)

Windows Phone builds store it in the application's local folder, again no documentation on format.

Android and Linux are in xml format, editable with a standard text editor.
The Android config files are package's shared prefs directory and the Linux config files are under ~/.config/.unity3d